# DirectX CreateOverlay function library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx

Hi I am using some classes a friend sent me, and I have an error on compile: Unresolved External Symbol on this function declaration:

```
int APIENTRY CreateOverlay(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

The classes are for drawing directX menus as an overlay. Problem is that I can't seem to find what library this function is in on the web.

Answer (score 1):

That's from some private library that is not available on the web. This sort of things usually are private, anyway.

Maybe your friend knows where this came from.